# Tailwind box shadow not applying

Tags: css, frontend, web-frontend, dropshadow

I'm trying to apply shadow around a box, usually, the shadow applied through tailwind pre-defined classes doesn't show on the top edge, so we need a bit of tweaking for having it shown on all four sides of the element. I tried to add shadow through the tailwind arbitrary class but it's still not showing.
My code looks like:

```
import React from "react";

export default function HomePage() {
  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col space-y-24">
      <div className="m-12 border border-[#e6e6e6] h-40 w-1/2 px-8 bg-white rounded-3xl drop-shadow-[10px_35px_60px_10px_rgba(60,60,60, 0.5)">
        <h1 className="text-3xl">Box</h1>
      </div>

      <div className="m-12 border border-[#e6e6e6] h-40 w-1/2 px-8 bg-white rounded-3xl shadow-[10px_35px_60px_10px_rgba(60,60,60, 0.5)">
        <h1 className="text-3xl">Box</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

And here is the complete sandbox example for this.
https://codesandbox.io/s/box-shadow-9zzvnd?file=/src/components/Homepage.js:0-532

Answer (score 0):

The shadow class is not a built-in class in tailwind. Instead, you can define your custom shadow using the box-shadow propertyy. The updated code should work with your `HomePage` component.

```
import React from "react";

export default function HomePage() {
  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col space-y-24">
       <div
        className="m-12 border border-[#e6e6e6] h-40 w-1/2 px-8 bg-white rounded-3xl"
        style={{
          boxShadow: "10px 35px 60px 10px rgba(60,60,60, 0.5)"
        }}
      >
        <h1 className="text-3xl">Box</h1>
      </div>

      <div
        className="m-12 border border-[#e6e6e6] h-40 w-1/2 px-8 bg-white rounded-3xl"
        style={{
          boxShadow: "10px 35px 60px 10px rgba(60,60,60, 0.5)"
        }}
      >
        <h1 className="text-3xl">Box</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Let me know if the code is still not working, I'll be happy to help

Answer (score 0):

In your example u dont have closing square bracket at the end of arbitrary value. Also you must not have spaces between values in `rgba()`. So:

`shadow-[10px_35px_60px_10px_rgba(60,60,60, 0.5)`

Should be:

`shadow-[10px_35px_60px_10px_rgba(60,60,60,0.5)]`

This works in tailwind 3.3.1